# Foxpro Database Connection in PHP via UNC Path

Tags: php, foxpro

Good day. I really need help.

I need to access a foxpro table in PHP.

When I access it using a local path as my data source, it works smoothly. 
But when I try to access a database file on another computer, it always prompt as invalid path, provided that I have access on the computer and the files are publicly shared. Here is my code:

```
$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection");
$server='172.0.0.8\server';
$conn->Open_basedir('Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=//172.0.0.8/server/sysprog/system/tempstk.dbf;Collating Sequence=MACHINE');  
// SQL statement to build recordset.
$rs = $conn->Execute("SELECT * FROM tempstk");

echo "<p>List of couriers:</p><hr>";
// Display all the values in the records set
while (!$rs->EOF) { 
    $fv = $rs->Fields("Prodcode");
    echo $fv->value."<br>\n";
    $rs->MoveNext();
} 
$rs->Close();
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume the webserver and the file server are windows? If you use the anonymous authorization in Internet Information Server the request impersonates as a windows user. In the standard configuration this will be IUSR. This user needs to be able to access the share and have read/write rights on the file.

IUSR is a local user. It is not included in the domain. So check your security settings of the share and see if IUSR is included.

Comment: Thanks Markus. Yes it is in windows. And, I am using XAMPP. Is IUSR used in IIS? And also,   I cannot access the share settings of the computer I am accessing. I don't have rights.

Comment: IUSR is created upon IIS install. You can switch to any other user in the IIS management console. Look for the "authorization" option there. In the properties you can configure what windows user to use, when accessing the page anonymously. Choose a user that has read/write access on the share. To read up the impersonation feature of IIS, you might want to take a look at the IIS website. They got some good documentation there

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an error in your connection string.

1. Try to change the IP address to the server's name.
2. Replace slashes with backslashes.
3. Remove DBF file name.

Here is an example I've just tested, and it works fine on my side:

```
Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=\\hostname\Shared Folders\somefolder\;Password="";Collating Sequence=MACHINE
```

Comment: @user3060463... Oleg is correct.  The critical thing is the connection is to the PATH WHERE the database files are located, not the specific .dbf you are trying to query.  Then you can select from any table in that path (or subpath if so structured)